# How to use firebase hosting wildcard redirects

Tags: firebase, firebase-hosting

I'm having some difficult with wildcard redirects for my firebase hosting:

I currently have a url setup like this:
`/post/123123`
where `123123` is the id of the post.
I want this to redirect to `/post?q=123123`.

I've tried this:

```
  "hosting": {
    "redirects": [ {
      "source": "/post/:postId",
      "destination": "/post?q=:postId",
      "type": 301
    }]
    "cleanUrls": true,
},
```

However, this doesn't do anything.

Is there anything that I am doing wrong?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Firebase: Pass url Param in URL Rewrite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45122296/firebase-pass-url-param-in-url-rewrite)